# Updating SVN working copy on Linux network share mount

Tags: linux, svn

I have a working copy of a repository on a Windows web server. If I update/commit the working copy using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) (1.7.6) or the command line (version 1.7.8) "svn update" on my Windows PC I have no problems.

However if I am on my Linux Subversion server (where the repository lives), accessing the working copy through a [CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) mount, without fail within 10 updates/commit the file .svn/wc.db will have become corrupted. Sometimes it is with the message

> svn: E200030: sqlite: database disk image is malformed" and sometimes it is a message like "svn: E155010: Pristine text 'd9a9a3ee5e6b4b0d35b​fef95601890afd80709'​ not present

I can clean up the corruption every time it occurs, but clearly I don't want to keep having to do that - I am struggling to work out the cause of the problem.

My Linux Subversion server is also using version 1.7.8. What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because the internal representation of the files or in the database are slightly [or much] different on a Linux and a Windows machine. Make your own copy on the Linux machine, and commit from that into the central repo, then pull it down on your windows machine.

In general, it's never a good idea to access the same copy of a version controlled repository from two different machines.

I use SVN for web work, and that's how I work - I do nearly all my work on a Linux machine, but I do have a repo on my windows laptop.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now copying across with much more success. I should have realised if I can't find the answer on Google already then I'm doing the wrong thing!